# Linq to SQL construct link table more efficient

Tags: .net, linq, performance, linq-to-sql

In my application I have 3 tables: Videos, Keywords and VideoKeywords

I use these to index videos by keywords. The problem is how to construct the VideoKeywords table efficient.

I do the following algorithm:

```
foreach (Video video in videosToIndex)
{
   Dictionary<string, int> words = Util.GetDistinctWordsInName(video.Name);

   video.VideoKeywords.Clear();
   foreach (string word in words.Keys)
   {
     int keywordId = keywords.Where(x => x.Name == word).Select(x =>   x.ID).FirstOrDefault();

    if (keywordId == 0)
    {
         Keyword kw = new Keyword() { Name = word };
         dc.Keywords.InsertOnSubmit(kw);
         dc.SubmitChanges();
         keywordId = kw.ID;
         keywords.Add(kw);
    }

    video.VideoKeywords.Add(new VideoKeyword() { VideoID = video.ID, KeywordID = keywordId, Occurrences = words[word] });
    }

     video.IndexedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
   }
   dc.SubmitChanges();
```

This works pretty well but I will be interested if there is a way of doing this without submitting data changes when having a new keyword. Can that keyword have a temporary Id?

Thanks a lot,

Radu

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to cache your keyword map in memory. That way you usually will not need to round-trip to the db to get the id (only for misses).

If you want to do the update in a single roundtrip you could abstract it to a stored proc.